# React Native infinite scroll in 2 directions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image]

I working on this scroll picker, do someone know how to make FlatList infinite when scroll top and down? Maybe there're some libraries with this funcionality?

Comment: can I as how would you handle an infinite up.For example what would the scroll render once I have scrolled passes one (UP direction).

Comment: content must be the same, for example, I scroll to number 1, before this number must be the last number of array (24)